# How to find the distance from the epicenter?

Tags: earthquakes

I don't know how to find the distance of the epicenter from New York 9:00UTC, Mexico city 9:00UTC and Seattle 9:00UTC

Comment: Could you please edit in some more details.  As it stands, what you are asking is unclear.

Comment: Its impossible to find the epicenter of an earthquake with just 3 locations, you need seismic arrival times, and a velocity model (to know how fast p/s waves travel). This question needs a lot more to be answerable.